# Bash echo-pipe into Mysql shell fails

Tags: php, mysql, regex, bash, shell

I have the following code as part of a script who's purpose is to duplicate a local website (in my Ubuntu 16.04 xenial server environment). The duplicated site's dir name, DB user name, and DB instance name is the same and is represented in the `${domain}` variable, while the `${rps}` holds Mysql root password, and ${sps} holds the duplicated site's DB user password.

The first part of the code works fine (`echo` and `read`). The second part fails (`echo`-`|` into Mysql shell):

```
echo "1/3: Please enter the domain of the site for duplication." && read domain
echo "2/3: Please enter the password for your Mysql root user." && read -s rps
echo "3/3: Please enter the password of the site's DB user." && read -s sps

echo "DROP USER IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost';" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}
echo "DROP database IF EXISTS test;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}
echo "CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY \"${sps}\";" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}
echo "CREATE database test;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO test@localhost;" | mysql -u root -p"${rps}
```

### The reason I echo and pipe Mysql commands:

It's done to ensure **variable substitution** for the `${sps`} variable (variable substitution cannot occur inside mysql shell, so it must be done outside and sent into the `mysql` shell).

### The problem

All echo-pipe operations fail, they start a secondary prompt.

### My question

Why are the echo-pipe operations fail, maybe this is a regex issue?

### Further details

The full code is available [here](https://github.com/benqzq/dwa/blob/master/dwa.sh).

Comment: `-p"${rps}` is missing a closing double-quote on each line. I'm voting to close this question as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also voting to close this question, but as I had time, I thought I would write some more info that may help.

A number of small errors are made in your code samples.

It is not recommended that you pass a password in a terminal as all users on the system can see the operation and password. For example, with a simple request to `ps auxwww`.

A better option is to use [`mysql_config_editor`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) to create a secure login that does not require a password when used from the localhost. You can then use something like `mysql --login-path=master` and no password is needed.

If you do really want to head down the passwords shown in plain text path, you should really use the long syntax, which is is:

```
mysql --password=plaintext --user=user --database=dbname < "mysql query"
```

Or

```
echo "mysql query" | mysql --password=plaintext --user=user --database=dbname
```

Or

```
mysql --password=plaintext --user=user --database=dbname << END

  mysql query to run;
  another mysql query to run;
  and another mysql query to run;

END
```

Or, possible the best looking at your code:

```
mysql --password=plaintext --user=user --database=dbname --execute='mysql query'
```

But, you should get a warning (which I can not remember now what is says) about the password being in plain sight or something.

To use one of you code samples, the script line would be (no `echo` needed):

```
mysql --user=root --password=${rps} --execute="DROP USER IF EXISTS 'test'@'localhost';"
```

Now why you code failed (as you now know).

The problem is `"` before the `${rps}`. Removing that `"` will work - but I would not use that code at all as it has other potential issues.

For example, entering the following for the `root` user password when your script request the password:

```
password; -e 'DROP ALL DATABASES'
```

This would cause all databases to be removed (if I got the syntax correct).